# VBA : Worksheet name as a variable is not accepted

Tags: excel, vba

The below exerpt from a VBA script won't work out for me. The goal is to copy specified cell contents from one worksheet to another, so that the content gets pasted below the prevailing last row on the other sheet, named wsX.

The script hangs up at row "Set tabla = .... " , but couldn't figure out why.
The error message sounds as:
"object variable or With block not set"

```
 Sub copythis()

Dim wsX As Worksheet

Select Case Worksheets("fromhere").Cells(2, 5)
    Case Is = 5
    Set wsX = Worksheets("do5")

    Case Is = 6
   Set wsX = Worksheets("do6")

    Case Is = 7
    Set wsX = Worksheets("do7")

    Case Else
    Msgbox "Wrong selection"
    Exit Sub
End Select

Dim tabla As Range:  Set tabla = wsX.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = tabla.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To 5
    Worksheets("fromhere").Range("N" & i).Copy wsX.Cells(LastRow + 1, i - 1)
Next
End Sub
```

Please let me know how to repair this code.

Comment: This code would fail if none of the cases matched - i.e., if `Worksheets("fromhere").cells(2, 5)` contained anything else besides 5, 6 or 7. Is that what happened?

Comment: Maybe add a `Case Else` to flag when none of the other cases are matched.

Comment: Absolutely perfect guess ! Adding "Case Else " did the job. Clearly " I couldn't see the wood for the trees ". Time to take a break.

Comment: I've come across a failure in my above code: Whenever I refer to worksheet "wsX" , an error message gets thrown : "Method range of Object '_Worksheet' failed "

If I remove wsX from the row 
Set tabla = wsX.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

the script rolls to end seamlessly, accompishes as designed.  What's wrong with my worksheet definition ?

Comment: What's the value of LastRow when there is a failure? Note that if you remove `wsX` the code can work but it will copy to the active sheet - which is fine but only if the sheet you want to have the data copied to is active! See here for debugging tips: [programming-excel-vba-debugging](https://krgreenlee.blogspot.com/2006/04/programming-excel-vba-debugging-for.html)

Comment: When debugging it, the value of the last row variable equals the sequence nr of the bottom row of the table. Which is correct. An interesting feature is, that when I use the Watch Window and go through the script row by row, then the running of the code does NOT get stuck. That's strange.